# Play Framework: Processing POST params?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

New to PlayFramwork and running into a roadblock.
The tutorial over @ https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms shows processing forms by binding the form inputs to a class. However, I want to process the HTML form without binding my fields to a class.

Example of my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="form/submit">
<input type="file" name="slider[1][file]" class="thumbnailUpload">
<input type="text" value="http://www.tapiture.com/shop/collection1" name="slider[1][url]" class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="slider[2][file]" class="thumbnailUpload">
<input type="text" value="http://www.tapiture.com/shop/collection1" name="slider[3][url]" class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="slider[2][file]" class="thumbnailUpload">
<input type="text" value="http://www.tapiture.com/shop/collection1" name="slider[3][url]" class="form-control">
</form>
```

I want to be able to process this in my action like so:

```
String url = form.get("slider")[0]["url"]
```

I've tried

```
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    final Map<String, String[]> values = body.asFormUrlEncoded();
```

And doing this, I can only access the values like so

```
value.get("slider[1][url]")
```

But I get

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@4d36e231
```

HELP!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The variable **values** contains a map where values are an array of strings. So using a **get** method returns an array. To access a value of a parameter look into a first element of it.

```
String value = values.get("slider[1][url]")[0];
```

I've also noticed that you're going to upload files. Don't forget that after changing form's **enctype** to:

```
<form method="POST" action="form/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you access POST data with:

```
final Map<String, String[]> values = body.asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();
```